# Under What Circumstances Would Demon Be Given Nectar Churned from Ocean

Tags: vishnu

The Gods and Demons United to churn the ocean of many gems.

In the end, Gods and Demons fought over who would have nectar.

Lord Vishnu disguises himself as Mohini and serves nectar to the Gods.

But didn't Demons help to churn nectar?

Under what circumstances would Lord Vishnu give them their 50% the nectar they helped churn?

Comment: I think the story as told in Puranas goes like this: When Lord Vishnu disguised as Mohini was about to distribute the amrita to both the Devas and the Asuras,Surya & Chandra Deva found that Rahu(one of the Asuras) disguised himself as a God and was seating in the row of the Devas..in a hurry to the drink Amrita ..these led to a commotion and a fight between the Devas and Asuras...Rahu was eventually beheaded by Vishnu's chakra..Then Vishnu decided that the Asuras were not fit to drink the Amrita....

Comment: So.it was not that Vishnu was reluctant to give the Asuras their share of the Amrita from the beginning...Rahu's greediness triggered the happenings..In any case..when Daitya Guru Sukra prayed and complained to Shiva about this unlawful and biased behavior towards the Asuras..Shiva gave Sukra the "Mrita Sanjeevani Vidya" by which he can bring dead asuras to life...so kind of a compensation..

Comment: There is answer for " Why Lord Vishnu disguised as Mohini cheated Demons?" but answer for your question is bit opinion based.

Comment: May I know why is this question being voted to close as opinion based?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I voted to close because the question is hypothetical / looks speculative, it's like asking, "under what circumstances Rama wouldn't have killed Ravana?" or "what should've Duryodhana done to bring Krishna to his side?"